# WebView - show dialog when user clicks a link

Tags: android, webview

I have an activity with a WebView. When the activity loads, I show an alert message which I dismiss on "onPageFinished" event.

What I need to do know, is show a ProgressBar when the user clicked on a link and the webview is loading it, and dismiss it when the loading is over. Similar to iPhone behaviour.

Is it possible?

10X :)
Udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

```
 final Activity activity = this;
 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
```

See also [here](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/04/adding-progress-bar-on-webview-android-tutorials/).

Comment: I am using WebViewClient for "onPageFinished" and "shouldOverrideUrlLoading", is it possible to do the same with "WebChromeClient"?